# Can the CMV Identify Widget work with an Elevation Image Service?

Tags: configurable-map-viewer, identify, image-service

I am using the CMV template but I have not been able to figure out if it is possible to configure the identify widget to return a pixel value (in this case an elevation value from a local image service).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?